# What is the animal in this video?

Tags: species-identification, ichthyology, species

I made some research however there seems to be a conflict with this animal's translation to my language and the original. So I couldn't find it. Do you mind helping me out ?

https://static.59saniye.com/videos/2018/04/21/20180421080742-6014_720.mp4

Some resources say pufferfish or Porcupinefish. Are these the same thing ?

Comment: You can do a search by common name (possibly in your language) in http://www.fishbase.org/search.php This site also has images for species in a family, like here for tetraodontidae: http://www.fishbase.org/identification/specieslist.php?famcode=448&areacode=

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a Northern pufferfish. It is called *Sphoeroides maculatus*.

> [image]
>   Source: https://www.flickr.com/photos/vims_photos/3570935564

You can confirm this on [FishBase](http://www.fishbase.org/summary/1181).

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in the field, so I can't identify the fish in your video; but it seems that pufferfish belong to the family Tetraodontidae, while porcupinefish are of the family Diodontidae. So, no, they are not the same thing.